# WebSecurity and Multitenancy - how to allow one instance of a username per tenant

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, simplemembership

With WebSecurity, Registering a user is like this:

```
WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password);
```

I know I can pass in custom parameters for my `User` table as well.  What I'm wondering is - in a multi-tenant scenario, how do I allow WebSecurity to enforce uniqueness on `Username` and `TenantId` columns, instead of just `Username`?

Related - when logging in, how do I specify a `TenantId' so that forms auth assigns a cookie only if the user exists on the specified tenant?

Unfortunately I can only extend WebSecurity and don't have the option to replace it.  Hopefully there's a way to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

We've solved this problem in the past by just adding a tenant identifier to the username when saving the user and again when verifying the login credentials.

The user doesn't see this, but it works brilliantly and easily!